# How to show Navigation Bar in a page based controller?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

As the title says, how can i show navigation bar in a page based controller of ios 5 ? I'm new  in iphone dev. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

will be helpful to you.